# What is the best way to dynamically fill a empty object literal with using modern standards like ES6?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, iteration

For my example i have a ordinary ES5 supported `for` loop that does what i want. It recently occurred to that all the new loops in ES6 are all prototype methods of the `Array` object.

With that in mind i wonder if there is a new best practice of iterating over a number s, or if `for` loops are still relevant. Seams like my example would be a reasonable use case for keeping the `for` loop relevant.

**EXAMPLE:** (Edited in reference to comment)

```
const entries = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  entries[`entry${i}`] = 'Some string';
}
```

Returns: `{entry0: "Some string", entry1: "Some string", entry2: "Some string", entry3: "Some string", entry4: "Some string"}`

Comment: A for loop is your best bet since this is an object and not an array.

Comment: btw, you get only 4 entries, not 5 as the value of `noOfEntries` suggest.

Comment: There was never a best practice for loops. It always depends on what you are looping over, what your condition is and what you are trying to do with the loop. Now, you just have more options.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Case-in-point: I would say that a `for/in` would be best to loop over objects. Someone else might say loop over `Object.keys`.

Comment: One thing to consider: if you have an object where the keys are a variation of incremental numbers, you often want an array instead.

Comment: The best way is to not use dynamic keys at all.

Comment: Who casted that close-vote for "general computing & hardware" ?

Comment: Of course for loops are still relevant. What made you think they wouldn't be? Efficiency and performance aside, your example is much easier on the eyes than some monstrosity like ``[...Array(noOfEntries).keys()].forEach(i => { entries[`entry${i+1}`] = 'Some string'; });`` which accomplishes basically the same thing...

Comment: @NinaScholz, good catch, i modified this from some project code i am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful when using the array functions, the more you of them you that you string together, the more loops you are creating behind the scenes. For example take this code:

```
const sum = [1,1,2,3,null,4,5,5,6]
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(i => i * 2)
  .reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)
```

You are creating 3 loops behind the scenes:

- One loop to filter the values
- One loop to multiply the values
- One loop to sum the values

And to your question, you could do something similar with these functions by creating an array, filling each will some value (otherwise it won't iterate), then doing a forEach.

```js
const entries = {};

new Array(5).fill(null).forEach((itm, i) => entries[`entry${i}`] = 'Some string')

console.log(entries)
```

In the end choose the best approach that works for your application. `for ... in/of` will almost always execute faster than the built-in array functions, so if you are doing lots of processing `for ... in/of` will be your best bet otherwise the built-in functions should work fine.

Comment: If you use my library [`enumerable-ts`](https://github.com/patrickroberts/enumerable-ts), `const sum = [1,1,2,3,null,4,5,5,6].where(Boolean).select(i => i * 2).aggregate((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)` only iterates the array once :)

Comment: the `new Array().fill()` methods comes up a lot in google searches. Given you first point of not going overboard with loops i think there still are some good use cases for `for` loops.

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers not to mention an array of 5 nulls is being created here just it iteratively modify another urelated object and be garbage collected as soon as it's filled.

Comment: In the scenario that you provided, I would stick to a old school `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You could map new objects with the wanted keys and assign all to the existent object.

Parts:

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
const
    entries = {},
    length = 5;

Object.assign(entries, ...Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => ({ [`entry${i}`]: 'Some string' })));

console.log(entries);
```

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but that seams like a very complicated solution. Interesting though. Thank you for the references. Learned something new.